# How can you make an electromagnet repel an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

I want to make both electromagnets repel each other, both electromagnets work on different microcircuits. I was hoping that two electromagnets would repel each other more strongly than one electromagnet and a piece of iron.
I also tried to make a change in the direction of the electric current, but this did not help, unfortunately. If I press the electromagnets against each other, on the contrary, they do not repel, but attract, and it does not matter which direction of the electric current is set.

Comment: Yes they do. You're probably doing something fundamentally wrong if you can't get it to happen. It's difficult to imagine what though without you posting photos of your setup. It's probably an easy fix.

Comment: What would make the electromagnets attract, even when one of them was reversed, is too small a field produced by one of them compared to the other, for example because of too small a current through it or too few turns – or both.

Comment: @PhilipWood Thanks,

Comment: I should have explained that if one electromagnet (I) is producing too small a field due to the current through its coil, the dominant effect will be induction of magetisation in its core by the other, stronger, electromagnet (2). The mechanism is that domains in the core of (1) will be aligned in the direction of the field of (2), or those already so aligned will be enlarged at the expense of oppositely aligned ones. This alignment means that the core of (1) will be attracted by (2) no matter which way round the current or the placement is.

Answer (score 2):

It does indeed matter which way the current is flowing. What you want is for the current to be flowing in *opposite directions* in the two coils. try this:

You hold the two electromagnets in your two hands. Current from your circuit is flowing in both coils. You bring them close together end-to-end and discover that they are attracting one another. then you take the magnet in your right hand and flip it over backwards by rotating your wrist 180 degrees so it is now pointing "backwards" relative to the other. In this configuration the magnets will repel one another.

Comment: Maybe the electromagnet, when connected, goes to another electromagnet and cannot push off, I will try to isolate them from each other upon contact.

Comment: And I don't use magnets, I only have electromagnets

Answer (score 0):

An electromagnet (2) will attract a piece of iron, previously unmagnetised. What happens is that the magnetic field of the electromagnet causes domains in the iron that are roughly lined up with field to get larger, so aligning the iron's predominant magnetisation with the field. [It can also happen that domains can flip direction to align with the field.] The result is that the iron is attracted to the electromagnet, whichever way round the current direction through the electromagnet.

Now suppose we wind a coil around the iron and pass a current through it. This will tend to magnetise the iron (align the domains). But if the current isn't strong enough, this alignment effect may be swamped by the effect described with in paragraph 1. It won't then be possible to observe repulsion between the two electromagnets, whichever way round they are placed and whichever way round the current is routed.

Advice: make sure that there is enough current through each electromagnet. Ideally test the fields they produce at the same distance from one pole of each.